# How to find the norm of this vector and the angles between him and other?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces, inner-products, angle

I am stuck on this exercise, so I would appreciate some help.
Here is the information given :
$$
\|\vec{a}\|= \sqrt2$$
$$ \|\vec{b}\|=\|\vec{d}\|=1$$
$$ \vec{a}\|\vec{d}$$
$$ \vec{c}=  \vec{a}+\vec{b}$$
$$\alpha=\angle( \vec{a}, \vec{b})=\frac\pi4
$$

What is the norm of the vector $\vec{c}$ ?
And what is the angle $\theta = \angle(\vec{c},\vec{d})$?

Thank you already !

What did I do: 
$$cos(\frac\pi4)=ab/||a|| ||b||$$
$$ab=\sqrt2$$

$$ ||c||^2 = ||a||^2 + 2*ab + ||b||^2$$
$$ ||c||^2 = 4  + 2*\sqrt2 + 1^2$$
$$ ||c||^2 =  5 + 2*\sqrt2$$
$$ ||c|| = \sqrt{ 5 + 2*\sqrt2}$$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, I will put on the post.

Comment: How do you get ab=$\sqrt{2}$? It seems there is a mistake here.

Comment: Otherwise it seems good! Then use the cosine formula again to get $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, I use the formula and get that, I know it is wrong. If I get only $$\sqrt5$$ it is correct, but with that  ab is wrong, so I can't move on with the exercise.

Comment: Here what did I do: $$cos(\frac\pi4) = \frac\sqrt22,Then  \frac\sqrt22 =ab/ 2 *1$$ What is wrong with this?

Comment: What is wrong is that $\|a\|$ is not equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec a\cdot\vec b$ is in fact equal to $\cos \frac{\pi}{4}\|a\|\|b\|$, that is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2}=1$.

Then $\|a\|^2$ is $\sqrt{2}^2$, that is $2$. Therefore you get $\|c\|=\sqrt{2+2+1}$ as expected.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was thinking that the norm of $\vec{a}$ was 2 instead of $\sqrt2$, so silly, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) +1 for a good quality post!